# genfromtxt dtype=None not getting a 2d-array

Tags: python, numpy, io, genfromtxt

I'm using this line to read a file

```
data_train = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', autostrip=True, dtype=float, missing_values="", filling_values='0')
```

since the values of a column may not share the same type, I'm getting a one dimensional array. Same if I use `dtype=None`). However, the values are either integer, or float, or missing values.

Can I fix this and get a 2d-array?

For example:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 3.3, , 2.2, 1  
1.1, 2.2, 4, , , , ,
```

Comment: Please post show sample data.

Comment: @Bob which are the different types? If it is float and int it would be much more straightforward to use float and eventually convert to int when needed...

Comment: I tried with dtype=float, but it doesn't work. It still generates a one dimensional arrray of objects

Comment: Your fields are separated by commas.  Use `delimiter=','`.

Comment: If it's giving you a 1d array, the dtype is probably complex, a mix of ints, floats, strings.  It does that if it can't force all elements into the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.nan_to_num(np.genfromtxt('test.txt', delimiter=','))
```

where `np.nan_to_num()` converts the `nan` entries that will be created where you have the missing data by `0`, obtaining for your example:

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  3.3,  0. ,  2.2,  1. ],
       [ 1.1,  2.2,  4. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

---

EDIT:
as clarified by @unutbu, @Warren Weckesser and in the dicussion below, depending on your system you can simply do (for me, on Windows 7 64 bit, Python 2.7.8 64 bit and [NumPy 1.9.0 downloaded here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) it doesn't work):

```
np.genfromtxt('test.txt', filling_values=0, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: @Bob you are right... I tried to make it work passing `missing_values` to `np.genfromtxt()` to avoid the `np.nan_to_num()` call but it didn't work...

Comment: I was using filling_values='0' because of a bug. but it's not working on mine (I'm using 1.8.0) without nan_to_num

Comment: @Bob: Did you try it along with `delimiter=','`?  That works for me with numpy 1.8.2.

Comment: That might be the reason

Comment: @Bob I'd say if you have to keep compatibility with NumPy < 1.9.0 you can use `np.nan_to_num(np.genfromtxt(...))` otherwise stick to the simpler solution passing `filling_values=0`

Comment: `np.genfromtxt('test.txt', filling_values='0', delimiter=',')` should work with numpy 1.8.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'd better update my version here :)

Comment: More hmmm... I just tried it in 1.8.0, and it worked.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that's really weird... I'm running into Windows 7, 64 bit, Python 2.7.5, exactly the same command

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser do you know possible reasons for this behavior?

Comment: Not offhand.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.9, Python 2.7.8 64 bit.

Comment: @Bob which operational system and Python version are you using?

Comment: @SaulloCastro I'm using Python 2.7.6 with Xubuntu 14

Comment: @Bob does `np.genfromtxt('test.txt', filling_values='0', delimiter=',')` work for you in NumPy 1.8.0?